# what is the best choice from those two tables?

Tags: database-design

what is the best choice from those tables??

- table A : keep DB simple with lower number of tables ... but i will find difficulties if i wanted to extract certain data from column of doses coz it's crowded with age ranges and doses and many routes of admin ... so if i wanted to make analysis for example: all doses given i.v. through all my DB.. i will face difficulties
- table B : it make things arranges in separated tables, so it will be easier to retrive data easily..but for one point i had many tables and i have to link them to each others
- now i ask: what is the best way to manage my DB and for querying data from it effectively and easily .. following example A or example B ???
  [image]

Comment: This is a flat out answer my homework question. I don't mind helping but at least put some thought in before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would say, example-B**

If you are using example A, then it is meaningless to save raw data in database; you can use plain text!

Example B supports searching for Doses, items related to Fever etc. (In example A you need to parse data).

Reducing the number of tables in a database is not an optimal solution. You have to normalize your data in order to select records based on a heavily *conditioned* search query (like, get all drugs for adults etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Option B is correct.

Quite simply: each row/column stores one and only one item of information

A multiple table design is quite normal: it comes out of the [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) process which starts with option A as your business data model.